# Is there an open-source (non GPL) implementation of a functional version of .NET StringBuilder?

Tags: f#, stringbuilder

I'm looking for a functional (as in, non-imperative) implementation of StringBuilder or equivalent. I've seen a couple of functional arrays implementation, but they don't support insertion natively. Bonus for open-source, non-(L?A?)GPL, bonus for F#, but I can translate from Haskell/OCaml/SML if needed.

Suggestions for algorithms welcome.

Comment: What features and performance do you want from StringBuilder?  O(1) insert and O(n) toArray?

Comment: I'm not too picky on the performance, but yes, ideally O(1) on insert and O(n) on conversion back to a seq/stream/array.

Comment: I doubt whether O(1) insert at an arbitrary location is possible for a functional data structure.  What exactly is wrong with the standard stringbuilder?

Comment: Are you sure StringBuilder.Insert is O(1)? I think it's O(n)... or did you mean append?

Comment: Also, what do you exactly mean by "functional"? Persistent?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer: Functional means non-destructive. An insert or append operation would return a new StringBuilder, such that pointers to the "old" StringBuilder still have the same value as before the operation. Think about the difference between a Dictionary (destructive) and a functional Map. I want the same kind of behavior in a StringBuilder.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: I need the operations to be non-destructive.

Comment: @fmr: such data structures are usually called 'persistent', not 'functional' ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure ), though they are of course pervasively (but not exclusively) used in functional programming.

Comment: @fmr: can you also clarify your complexity requirements? Are you sure you want O(1) insert or did you mean O(1) append?

Comment: Immutable is another name often used for none destructive data types.

Comment: Doing O(1) insert is definitely possible (see my answer). However, you'll need to sacrifice some performance of the other operations.

Comment: @fmr: After thinking this was a pipe dream, following Tomas' suggestion I implemented it as a linked-list. The code is in my answer. I've tested it quite a bit (using 1M inserts) and it performs reasonably well. I _think_ it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StringBuilder`s advantage over `string` is due to minimizing allocations. It pre-allocates a buffer to avoid allocating for every insert/append. This requires mutability--some object must own (and mutate) the buffer.

Incidentally, `System.String` already fits (what I can make of) your description: it's immutable and supports concatenation, [insertion<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx), and [removal<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx).

#### UPDATE

Tomas' idea intrigued me. Taking his idea, here's what I came up with

```
type StringBuilder =
  private
  | Empty
  | StringBuilder of int * string * int * StringBuilder
  member this.Length =
    match this with 
    | Empty -> 0
    | StringBuilder(_, _, n, _) -> n
  override this.ToString() =
    let rec rev acc = function
      | Empty -> acc
      | StringBuilder(idx, str, _, bldr) -> rev ((idx, str)::acc) bldr
    let buf = ResizeArray(this.Length)
    for idx, str in rev [] this do buf.InsertRange(idx, str)
    System.String(buf.ToArray())

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module StringBuilder =
  let empty = Empty
  let length (bldr:StringBuilder) = bldr.Length
  let insert index str bldr = 
    if index < 0 || index > (length bldr) then invalidArg "index" "out of range"
    StringBuilder(index, str, str.Length + bldr.Length, bldr)
  let create str = insert 0 str empty
  let append str bldr = insert (length bldr) str bldr
  let remove index count (bldr:StringBuilder) = create <| bldr.ToString().Remove(index, count)
```

Usage

```
let bldr = 
  StringBuilder.create "abcdef"
  |> StringBuilder.insert 1 "xyz"
  |> StringBuilder.append "123"
  |> StringBuilder.remove 1 2

bldr.ToString() //azbcdef123
```

It's persistent and insertion is O(1).

Comment: Insertion actually isn't O(1), its O(no of insertions) due to the length check, I think the O for `ToString` is also to low, as at a minimum you are effectively sorting by idx which would make it O(n logn)

Comment: You're right. You could forego the length check on insert and throw in `ToString` to make it O(1). Even though the check makes it O(insertions) it's very efficient.

Comment: I'm quite sure `string.Length` is O(1).

Comment: there is a recursive step, you sum up all the lengths which makes length O(n. insertions)

Comment: You're right it's O(insertions), but since `string.Length` is O(1) it's very cheap.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: I changed it so the length is cached with each instance. Inserts are now O(1).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any implementation that would do exactly what you want. However, I don't think you can ever get O(1) complexity of inserting (at arbitrary index) and O(n) complexity of iteration over the results.

If you're happy to sacrifice the complexity of insertion, then you can use just `string` as Daniel suggests. On the other side, if you're willing to sacrifice the complexity of `toString`, then you can make immutable data structure with O(1) insertion at any location by using a list of strings and indices:

```
type InsertList = IL of (int * string) list 

// Insert string 'str' at the specified index 
let insertAt idx str (IL items) = IL (idx, str)::items

// Create insert list from a string
let ofString str = IL [str]
```

The conversion to string is a bit more tricky. However, I think you can get O(n log n) complexity by using a mutable `LinkedList` and inserting individual characters at the right location by iterating over the insertions from the end. The use of `LinkedList` is going to be locallized to `toString`, so the data structure is still purely functional.

Comment: A minimum conversion to a string will be at least O(n) as you will have to reverse the list to deal with `insertAt 0 "World"` then `insertAt 0 "Hello"`, and then I think the best would involve a stable sort, I suspect the best case may actually be O(n*log n * m) where there are `m` insertions, as you have to deal with overlaps

Comment: I took a stab at implementing your idea and included it in my answer. Does it look like what you had in mind?