# Multiplying a string in F#

Tags: string, f#

I have a question I am rather unsure about.

My questions is as follows

```
let myFunc (text:string) (times:int) = ....
```

What I want this function to do is put the string together as many times as specified by the `times` parameter.

`if input = "check " 3` I want the output string = `"check check check"`

I have tried with a loop, but couldn't seem to make it work.

Anyone?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually the function is already in [String](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-stringmodule.html) module:

```
let multiply text times = String.replicate times text
```

To write your own function, an efficient way is using `StringBuilder`:

```
open System.Text

let multiply (text: string) times =
    let sb = new StringBuilder()
    for i in 1..times do
        sb.Append(text) |> ignore
    sb.ToString()
```

If you want to remove trailing whitespaces as in your example, you can use `Trim()` member in `String` class to do so.

Comment: damn, didnt notice, Thanks buddy!

Comment: It's more like `iter` since each step doesn't create a new `StringBuilder`.

Comment: True, but given that `Append` returns the `StringBuilder` instance, it fits nicely with `fold`. It's possible to create [an immutable string builder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8346765/162396) if you're going for purity.

Comment: Why not just use `String.replicate` instead of defining a new function?

Comment: @missingfaktor: I already said that in the first part of the answer. The 2nd part is just another possibility.

Comment: You defined a new function `multiply` using `String.replicate`. What I said was - why not advise using `String.replicate` directly?

Comment: He wants it with parameters in another order. I should have said it more clearly.

Comment: Okay, I guessed so, so I provided an alternative way in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on pad's solution, given that it's just a fold:

```
let multiply n (text: string) = 
  (StringBuilder(), {1..n})
  ||> Seq.fold(fun b _ -> b.Append(text))
  |> sprintf "%O"
```

Or use [`String.replicate`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-stringmodule.html) from F# standard's lib.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure functional "do-it-yourself" version for F# learning purposes, then something like the following snippet will do:

```
let myFunc times text =
    let rec grow result doMore =
        if doMore > 0 then
            grow (result + text) (doMore- 1)
        else
            result
    grow "" times
```

Here is the test:

```
> myFunc 3 "test";;
val it : string = "testtesttest"
```

Otherwise you should follow the pointer about the standard F# library function `replicate` given in **pad's** answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`String.replicate`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-stringmodule.html) already provides the functionality you're looking for.

If for some reason you want the arguments reversed, you can do it as follows:

```
(* A general function you should add to your utilities *)
let flip f a b = f b a
 
let myFunc = flip String.replicate
```

Answer (score -1):

In a simple recursive fashion:

```
let rec dupn = function
|s,1 -> s
|s,n -> s ^ dupn(s, n-1)
```

Comment: Using `^` is for ML compatibility, better use `+`. Better yet, don't use concatenation in a tight loop like this, it is going to be very slow with a near exponential performance.