# Why does traversing a large binary tree result in a stack overflow even when using continuation-passing style?

Tags: f#, mono, binary-tree, tail-recursion, continuation-passing

Chapter 9 of the book *Expert F# 3.0* shows how to use continuation-passing style to avoid stack overflows when traversing binary trees. I have written tree traversal code that is almost identical to the code from the book, but I get stack overflows nevertheless. My code is as follows:

```
type 'a Tree =
  | Leaf   of 'a
  | Branch of 'a Tree * 'a Tree

let rec mkLeftLeaningTree n tree =
  if n = 0 then
    tree
  else
    Branch (mkLeftLeaningTree (n - 1) tree, Leaf "right")

let leftLeaningTree1 = Leaf "left"
let leftLeaningTree2 = mkLeftLeaningTree 30000 leftLeaningTree1
let leftLeaningTree3 = mkLeftLeaningTree 30000 leftLeaningTree2
let leftLeaningTree4 = mkLeftLeaningTree 30000 leftLeaningTree3
let leftLeaningTree5 = mkLeftLeaningTree 30000 leftLeaningTree4
let leftLeaningTree6 = mkLeftLeaningTree 30000 leftLeaningTree5

let sizeContAcc tree =
  let rec worker acc tree cont =
    match tree with
      | Leaf _               -> cont (acc + 1)
      | Branch (left, right) -> worker acc left  (fun acc ->
                                worker acc right cont)
  worker 0 tree id
```

Loading this into the F# interactive environment and evaluating the expression `sizeContAcc leftLeaningTree6` makes the stack overflow. Why is this?

Comment: You actually overflow much earlier, when creating the leftLeaningTree2: `let leftLeaningTree2 = mkLeftLeaningTree 30000 leftLeaningTree1`.

Comment: Whether the computation of `leftLeaningTree2` overflows the stack depends on the particular platform. If you get an overflow at this point, you can replace the occurrences of `30000` by lower numbers. If this, in turn, results in `sizeContAcc leftLeaningTree6` not overflowing the stack, you can use more tree construction steps (adding `leftLeaningTree7` and so on).

Comment: That is indeed true, I was wondering if you were running this on Linux, which has a bigger stack than windows (1MB ;-).

Comment: Yes, I am running this on Linux. Does this problem also show up on Windows after having tuned parameters accordingly?

Comment: I want to add that I am using F# 4.0.

Comment: I would suspect FSI in this case. At count 270,001 (19 trees with 15,000 leafs) it doesn't overflow. Can you make sure that FSI is running in 64-bit if you are using it, otherwise have it compiled in Release mode, 64-bit with Optimization and Tail Calls turned on.

Comment: In FSI the options would be --optimize --tailcalls but I'm not familiar with mono (which I assume you are using).

Comment: I have tried to run `fsharpi` with options `--optimize` and `--tailcalls`, but the stack still overflows. I have also tried to compile my F# code using these options, but the stack overflow also occurs then.

Comment: That is very unfortunate. I would suspect either a bug or some setting in mono. I will post some more details, but I'm afraid that might not help you directly, since it won't be mono. I added that tag to the Q.

Comment: Can you get rid of the stack overflow on Microsoft .NET by using `--optimize` and `--tailcalls`?

Comment: Yes. See my (not really...) answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this might not help you to actually fix the issue but maybe it provides some pointers in where to look. First, the code and the setup. I decreased the tree size itself to make it work on Windows. The rest is .NET 4.6, 64-bit, win7, in VS2015 Update3.

```
type 'a Tree =
    | Leaf   of 'a
    | Branch of 'a Tree * 'a Tree

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    ///https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477122/why-does-traversing-a-large-binary-tree-result-in-a-stack-overflow-even-when-usi



    let rec mkLeftLeaningTree n tree =
      if n = 0 then
        tree
      else
        Branch (mkLeftLeaningTree (n - 1) tree, Leaf "right")



    let leftLeaningTree1 = Leaf "left"
    let leftLeaningTree2 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree1
    let leftLeaningTree3 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree2
    let leftLeaningTree4 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree3
    let leftLeaningTree5 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree4
    let leftLeaningTree6 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree5
    let leftLeaningTree7 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree6
    let leftLeaningTree8 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree7
    let leftLeaningTree9 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree8
    let leftLeaningTree10 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree9
    let leftLeaningTree11 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree10
    let leftLeaningTree12 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree11
    let leftLeaningTree13 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree12
    let leftLeaningTree14 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree13
    let leftLeaningTree15 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree14
    let leftLeaningTree16 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree15
    let leftLeaningTree17 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree16
    let leftLeaningTree18 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree17
    let leftLeaningTree19 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree18
    let leftLeaningTree20 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree19
    let leftLeaningTree21 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree20
    let leftLeaningTree22 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree21
    let leftLeaningTree23 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree22
    let leftLeaningTree24 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree23
    let leftLeaningTree25 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree24
    let leftLeaningTree26 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree25
    let leftLeaningTree27 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree26
    let leftLeaningTree28 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree27
    let leftLeaningTree29 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree28
    let leftLeaningTree30 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree29
    let leftLeaningTree31 = mkLeftLeaningTree 15000 leftLeaningTree30

    let sizeContAcc tree =
      let rec worker acc tree cont =
        match tree with
          | Leaf _               -> cont (acc + 1)
          | Branch (left, right) -> worker acc left  (fun acc ->
                                    worker acc right cont)
      worker 0 tree id



    sizeContAcc leftLeaningTree31  |> printfn "%A"

    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

This is compiled with tail calls, optimize in Release mode:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe
>   -o:obj\Release\ConsoleApplication8.exe --debug:pdbonly --noframework --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Release\ConsoleApplication8.XML --optimize+ --platform:x64 -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETFramework\v4.0\4.4.0.0\FSharp.Core.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\mscorlib.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Core.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\System.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Numerics.dll"
>   --target:exe --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors --subsystemversion:6.00 --highentropyva+ --sqmsessionguid:057b9ccf-c89e-4da6-81ab-5295156e7a19 "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.AssemblyAttributes.fs"
>   AssemblyInfo.fs Program.fs  1>    ConsoleApplication8 ->
>   C:\Users\userName\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\StackOverflow6\ConsoleApplication8\bin\Release\ConsoleApplication8.exe

So with 31 trees this works:

```
 .\ConsoleApplication8.exe
450001
```

Now let's compile this in Debug mode:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe
>   -o:obj\Debug\ConsoleApplication8.exe -g --debug:full --noframework --define:DEBUG --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication8.XML --optimize- --tailcalls- --platform:anycpu32bitpreferred -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETFramework\v4.0\4.4.0.0\FSharp.Core.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\mscorlib.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Core.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\System.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6\System.Numerics.dll"
>   --target:exe --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors --subsystemversion:6.00 --highentropyva+ --sqmsessionguid:057b9ccf-c89e-4da6-81ab-5295156e7a19 "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.AssemblyAttributes.fs"
>   AssemblyInfo.fs Program.fs  1>    ConsoleApplication8 ->
>   C:\Users\userName\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\StackOverflow6\ConsoleApplication8\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication8.exe

And, oops:

```
> .\ConsoleApplication8.exe
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

So what is the difference?

In the Release version there are 9 `tail` calls, if you decompile the IL, and I assume this is represented by some sort of while loop.

```
IL_0073: ldloc.s 6
IL_0075: tail.
IL_0077: call int32 [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives/HashCompare::GenericComparisonWithComparerIntrinsic<!a>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.IComparer, !!0, !!0)
```

In the Debug version, this will be missing:

```
L_007d: ldloc.s 6
IL_007f: call int32 [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives/HashCompare::GenericComparisonWithComparerIntrinsic<!a>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.IComparer, !!0, !!0)
IL_0084: ret
```

For a simpler example to test you can check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40299925/concatenating-strings-in-f-number-of-times/40301046#40301046) as it has both a recursive and tail recursive version of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess was that you are stacking functions on top of each other in your cont argument, I understood it as a stack that might overflow (whereas it is a heap as explained by Wolfgang in a comment) but I did some tests using a cont argument and it didn't cause any stackoverflow. Instead, I had a significant slowdown and finally reached a memory overflow.

A solution to your specific problem would be to explicitly store the trees you will need to explore in a list (you will still be limited by the maximum size for a list) :

```
let sizeContAcc tree =
  let rec worker acc tree contList =
    match tree with
      | Leaf _ -> 
        match contList with
        | [] -> acc+1
        | t::cl -> worker (acc+1) t cl
      | Branch (left, right) -> worker acc left (right::contList)
  worker 0 tree []
```

It works and instantly gives me 150001 for leftLeaningTree6.

Comment: I don't think this is right - none of the operations in `sizeContAcc` should result in deeper stack frames like your `(f >> f)` example does.

Comment: The term “stack” in “stack overflow” does not refer to any stack structure in an F# program. It refers to the system stack. An F# program internally uses a stack and a heap. While I am building kind of a stack of functions in my code, this nested function expression is build on the heap (which is larger than the stack); so it should not cause the system stack to overflow. The `overflower` and the `nonOverflower` in your example are fundamentally different. The former applies the function `f` exponentially often, the latter only linearily often.

Comment: Thank you Wolfgang, I just reread my code and you are indeed right. I removed the wrong example and added a remark based on further tests.