# F# "Stateful" Computation Expression

Tags: f#, functional-programming, computation-expression

I'm currently learning F# and hitting a few stumbling blocks; I think a lot of it is learning to think functionally.

One of the things I'm learning at the moment are computation expressions, and I want to be able to define a computation expression that handles some tracking state, e.g:

```
let myOptions = optionListBuilder {
    let! opt1 = {name="a";value=10}
    let! opt2 = {name="b";value=12}
}
```

I want to be able to have it so that `myOptions` is a `Option<'T> list`, so each `let!` bind operation effectively causes the builder to "track" the defined options as it goes along.

I don't want to have to do it using mutable state - e.g. having a list maintained by the builder and updated with each `bind` call.

Is there some way of having it so that this is possible?

---

**Update**: The resultant `Option<'T> list` type is just representative, in reality I'll likely have an `OptionGroup<'T>` type to contain a list as well as some additional information - so as Daniel mentioned below, I could use a list comprehension for a simple list.

Comment: Two things: I would suggest against creating a new type named `Option` since one of those exists in the language already.  Maybe `OptionWithItem` or something of that sort.  Second, if you have an anwer, you should post it down with the other answers.  You can still mark the one that helped you get there as "the" answer, but it still clearly separates question from answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a string builder computation expression [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18596186/901059).

```
open System.Text

type StringBuilderUnion =
| Builder of StringBuilder
| StringItem of string

let build sb =
    sb.ToString()

type StringBuilderCE () =
    member __.Yield (txt : string) = StringItem(txt)
    member __.Yield (c : char) = StringItem(c.ToString())
    member __.Combine(f,g) = Builder(match f,g with
                                     | Builder(F),   Builder(G)   ->F.Append(G.ToString())
                                     | Builder(F),   StringItem(G)->F.Append(G)
                                     | StringItem(F),Builder(G)   ->G.Append(F)
                                     | StringItem(F),StringItem(G)->StringBuilder(F).Append(G))
    member __.Delay f = f()
    member __.Zero () = StringItem("")
    member __.For (xs : 'a seq, f : 'a -> StringBuilderUnion) =
                    let sb = StringBuilder()
                    for item in xs do
                        match f item with
                        | StringItem(s)-> sb.Append(s)|>ignore
                        | Builder(b)-> sb.Append(b.ToString())|>ignore
                    Builder(sb)

let builder1 = new StringBuilderCE ()
```

Noticed the underlying type is immutable (the contained `StringBuilder` is mutable, but it doesn't have to be).  Instead of updating the existing data, each yield combines the current state and the incoming input resulting in a new instance of `StringBuilderUnion`  You could do this with an F# list since adding an element to the head of the list is merely the construction of a new value rather than mutating the existing values.

Using the `StringBuilderCE` looks like this:

```
//Create a function which builds a string from an list of bytes
let bytes2hex (bytes : byte []) =
    string {
        for byte in bytes -> sprintf "%02x" byte
    } |> build

//builds a string from four strings
string {
        yield "one"
        yield "two"
        yield "three"
        yield "four"
    } |> build
```

Noticed the `yield` instead of `let!` since I don't actually want to use the value inside the computation expression.

Comment: Marked as answer as it led me to come up with a CE builder that uses a near-identical system.

Answer (score 3):

**SOLUTION**

With the base-line StringBuilder CE builder provided by mydogisbox, I was able to produce the following solution that works a charm:

```
type Option<'T> = {Name:string;Item:'T}

type OptionBuilderUnion<'T> =
    | OptionItems of Option<'T> list
    | OptionItem of Option<'T>

type OptionBuilder () =
    member this.Yield (opt: Option<'t>) = OptionItem(opt)
    member this.Yield (tup: string * 't) = OptionItem({Name=fst tup;Item=snd tup})
    member this.Combine (f,g) = 
        OptionItems(
            match f,g with
            | OptionItem(F), OptionItem(G) -> [F;G]
            | OptionItems(F), OptionItem(G) -> G :: F
            | OptionItem(F), OptionItems(G) -> F :: G
            | OptionItems(F), OptionItems(G) -> F @ G
        )
    member this.Delay f = f()
    member this.Run (f) = match f with |OptionItems items -> items |OptionItem item -> [item]

let options = OptionBuilder()

let opts = options {
        yield ("a",12)
        yield ("b",10)
        yield {Name = "k"; Item = 20}
    }

opts |> Dump
```

Comment: In `Combine`, is ordering of the resulting list important?  If not, then you should avoid the use of `@` where possible since it is a very expensive operation.  In the three cases where you have an `OptionItem` you can simple cons (`::`) the item with the list like this: `F::G` (assuming F is an item and G is a list).

Comment: @mydogisbox I noticed that when I ran it in Linqpad - the ordering isn't important for the example I gave, but I would indeed ensure the singular part of the combination ended up as the new head of the list to ensure ordering.

Comment: @mydogisbox I've just made changes to use the less expensive `::` and to have it so that the item ends up at the head position.

Answer (score 2):

F# supports list comprehensions out-of-the-box.

```
let myOptions =
    [
        yield computeOptionValue()
        yield computeOptionValue()
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was aware of this, I should perhaps edit my question to indicate that the resultant list is just an example, and in actual fact the list will be represented by some container type with additional methods etc.

Comment: In that case, a simpler option might be defining an `ofList` function for your type.

Comment: it indeed might be, but if I want to do any particular manipulation transparently then I sort of need the computation expression, no? For example, if I want to be able to do `let! x = ("n",12)` and have the tuple converted to the `Option<int>` type automatically.

Comment: Since you're apparently doing black magic you're on your own. :)